# How to convert a 2x2 map to a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, matrix, dictionary, grid

*Python*

How do I turn a grid of:

```
x,x
x,x
```

to a list of lists?:

```
[['x', 'x'], ['x', 'x']]
```

Comment: why 3 rows of x's?? do you mean `[['x', 'x'], ['x', 'x']]`? Also is the grid a text file?

Comment: Yes, I just fixed the post and yes, the grid is a plain text file.

Answer (score 6):

It's as simple as:

```
with open(...) as f:
    list_of_lists = [line.strip().split(",") for line in f]
# use list_of_lists
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to get a list of lists:

```
gridlist = []
f = open('**path/to/file/here**')

for line in f:
    a = line.strip().split(',')
    gridlist.append(a)
print gridlist
```

Comment: I'm getting this as a result: '[['P', 'P\n'], ['P', 'P\n']]'

Comment: How do I eliminate the \n?

Comment: @user2581724 but just use jonsharpe's solution. it's better than mine

Answer (score 0):

Make a function to go through each line and split them by the commas.

```
def get_gridas_list(filename):
    # an empty list to store your data
    grid_list = []
    # with is the safest way to open a text document
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        # iterate through all the lines in the file
        for line in file:
            #split is a function associated with strings
            # "x,x".split(',') -> ['x', 'x']
            grid_list.append(line.strip().split(','))
    # return the now full list of lists
    return grid_list
```

Comment: Thank You but I'm getting this: '[['P', 'P\n'], ['P', 'P\n']]'

Answer (score 0):

Use readline from file and then the split-method

```
list = []

line_from_file = '23wda, wa0dw'

parts = line_from_file.split(', ')

list.append([parts[0], parts[1]])

line_from_file = '234f4fda, wa03d2dw'

parts = line_from_file.split(', ')

list.append([parts[0], parts[1]])

print(list)
```